# SiteScout oauth2 authentication

Tags: authentication, curl

their API: http://www.sitescout.com/support/api/#authentication
states that i should submit a POST request to https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token with Authorization header set to my own credentials ( base64_encode("username:password") ). below is an example request:

```
POST https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sitescout.com
Authorization: Basic YmVldGhvdmVuOmxldG1laW4=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 41

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=STATS
```

i should be getting something like this:

```
{

    "scope": "STATS",
    "access_token": "7ebe55b54ee12a8ee07329f1cefd6de6",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600

}
```

my code:

```
  $url = "https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token";
  $ch = curl_init();

  $headers  = array(
    "POST https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1",
    "HOST: api.sitescout.com",
    "Authorization: Basic ZGlnaWZ1c2UtYXBpOnh1M2pkODll****",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Length: 41"
  );

  $post_fields = array(
    'grant_type' => 'credentials'
  );

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  //$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  var_dump($output);
```

is not working. could someone please point me to the right direction? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Auth header should like:

```
$header = array(
      "POST https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1",
      "HOST: api.sitescout.com",
      "Authorization: {$this->_auth_header}",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Accept: application/json",
      "Content-Length: 41"
    );
```

You can also use this API Wrapper Class to make Auth and fatch API reporting information.
It includes all functions to fatch Campaigns, Sites, Creatives etc..

https://github.com/lokeshpahal/sitescout

Comment: i am getting error "Invalid access token provided",can you help me ?

Comment: It seems the access token provided o fetch the information is not correct, how did you  fetch the Access token?

Comment: I used your code from : "https://github.com/lokeshpahal/sitescout".I simply pass my credentials at the time to creating object something like this : "$api = new API('CLIENT_ID','CLIENT_SECRET');" Is there anything else that i have to set ?

Comment: @s4suryapal,SiteScout has made some changes in their API's, so I have updated the API code as per the SiteScout API changes. now you can use the API Wrapper to access the SiteScout API (https://github.com/lokeshpahal/sitescout)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what errors that you met, but I think there must be something wrong in the header parameters based on your sample code. "POST https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1" should not be a part of the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

Digifuse, were you able to make it work?

If not, I believe the issue should be on this part:

```
'grant_type' => 'credentials'
```

Which actually should be:

```
'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
```